# How to define multiple many-to-one relations between two Doctrine tables?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I've got a problem with doctrine with Symfony when I try to define to relations Many-to-one between the table Challenge and User getting the next error.

Error when I try to define:

[image]

The table User has the attribute: id, challengesMaked, challengesReceived and the table Challenge has these atributes: id, idUser1, idUser2 where idUser1 I want to relation with id from User and idUser2 I want to relation with id from User too. The relation between User and Challenge are One to Many (One user can challenge to another user) and between Challenge to User are Many to One (One challenge is received only by a User)

So, how can I define this attributes in my entity to fix my bug. Right now, in my User Entity I have defined these attributes like ...

```
    /**
 * @var Challenge ArrayCollection
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="\MQL\PlayerBundle\Entity\Challenge", mappedBy="idUser1", cascade={"persist"})
 */
protected $challengesMaked;

/**
 * @var Challenge ArrayCollection
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="\MQL\PlayerBundle\Entity\Challenge", mappedBy="idUser2", cascade={"persist"})
 */    
protected $challengesReceived;
```

And in the Challenge Entity I have defined ...

```
    /**
 * @var User ArrayCollection
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="challengesMaked")
 **/    
protected $idUser1;                 //Challenger

/**
 * @var User ArrayCollection
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="challengesReceived")
 **/    
protected $idUser2;     //Challenged
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Fist of all: **clear your cache**. You haven't referenced an `id` column as the exception-message states, at least in the code snippets you posted ... looks like outdated mapping-information is being used here. Further, I think you could easily improve this setup by just adding a single `finished` attribute to the challenge itself and removing the `challengesMaked` reference. Otherwise you'd have the same challenges fetched twice if you fetch your user-entity in some cases. If you need the finished challenges -> use a custom repository method / query to fetch them. got the point?

Comment: Default for a joinColumn is `name: "<fieldname>_id"` & `referencedColumnName: "id"`. `FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User` (you should also be using `Model\User`) doesn't have an `id` (which is why you are getting the `id` exception) so you have to add it to your concrete class. Also your association should be pointing at your concrete class so you can add the corresponding getters and setters rather than the abstract `FOSUserBundle:User` class(es).. Oh yeah, and a mappedSuperclass (`FOSUserBundle:User`) can't have associations.

Comment: Under which namespace is your User entity?